# Puppet Error: ghostscript install failing

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to run puppet to install ghostscript, but it's throwing error messages and am not sure what is wrong.

Here are the messages:

> Notice: /Stage[last]/Macports/Exec[install ghostscript]/returns: Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, can't read "result": no such variable
>
> Error: /usr/bin/sudo /opt/local/bin/port install 'ghostscript' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
>
> Error: /Stage[last]/Macports/Exec[install ghostscript]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/bin/sudo /opt/local/bin/port install 'ghostscript' returned 1 instead of one of [0]

Comment: Since you give us only the error messages to go on, the most I can say is that the command `/opt/local/bin/port`, apparently belonging to MacPorts, is not working in the context of your catalog run.  If it works when you run it from the command line, then it may be that it needs environment configuration when run under Puppet.  When Puppet runs a command, it provides a very sparse environment to it by default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve